# Showing that infinite product of random variables goes to zero: $\prod^\infty X_i \rightarrow 0 \text{ a.s.}$

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am doing the following exercise:

Let $X$ be a strictly positive rv with $\mathbb E[X]=1$ but $X \neq 1$ almost surely. Let $X_1, X_2 \dots$ be iid with same distribution as $X$. Now let $M_0=1$ and 
$$M_n = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k$$
The task is to show that $M_n \rightarrow 0$ almost surely. Some sub-problems preceding showing this convergence was to show that $\mathbb E[\ln(X)]<0$ and that $\mathbb E[M_n]=1$. That is straightforward. Then one is asked to show the said convergence by considering 
$$
M_n = e^{\sum^n \ln X_k}
$$
So I have tried to reason that in order for $e^{\sum^n \ln X_k} \rightarrow 0$ almost surely, we need $\sum^n \ln X_k \rightarrow -\infty$ almost surely. Here I have some doubts as to how to proceed. I have tried to think in terms of Borel-Cantelli and show this by making an argument along the lines of: for any $N \in (-\infty, 0]$ 
$$
\mathbb P(M_n < N \text{ eventually}) = 1
$$
etc but it seems that this ends up requiring me to know things about the distribution of $M_n$ which I know nothing about (except its mean).

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Strictly speaking (i.e., of convergence of an infinite product) it is not convergence if the sequence of partial products converges to $0$

Comment: $n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n \ln{X_k}\rightarrow E[\ln(X)]$ a.s.

Comment: $\log M_n = n E \log X_1 +o(n)$ a.s.

Comment: You can find an alternative proof here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876399/limit-value-of-a-product-martingale/876406#876406

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First write,

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i &= \exp \left ( \lim_{n \to \infty} n \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log(X_i) \right ) .
\end{align}
$$

Now by the SLLN we have $n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log(X_i) \stackrel{\text{a.s.}}{\to} \text{E}[\log(X_1)]$.  But Jensen's inequality (along with strict concavity of the log function and non-degeneracy of $X_1$) gives $ \text{E}[\log(X_1)] < \log[\text{E}(X_1)] = 0$ and hence the above limit is zero with probability one.

Comment: You can't take the $n$ outside of the limit, when the limit depends on $n$... That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\log(x)\lt x-1$, for $x\gt0$ and $x\ne1$
$$
\mathbb{E}(\log(X))\lt\mathbb{E}(X-1)=0
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^n x_k
&=\exp\!\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log(x_k)\right)\\
&\sim\exp\!\left(n\,\mathbb{E}(\log(X))\right)\\[9pt]
&\to0
\end{align}
$$