# I.I.D. random variables almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ be strictly positive r.v. such that $X$ not equal to 1 almost surely and  $\mathbb{E}(X)=1$. Let $X_1, X_2,...$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables each having the same distribution as $X$.
Let $M_0=1$ and $$M_n=\exp\left(\sum^n_{i=0} \ln(X_i)\right).$$

How to show that $M_n\to0$ almost surely?

Comment: This is false. Just let $X_n=1$ for all $n$. You need the added assumption that $X$ is not a.s. 1, or similar.

Comment: Just thinking out loud: if $X_i$ are iid, so are $\ln(X_i)$, and so $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^n \ln (X_i) \to \mathbb{E}[X_i] = 0$$ a.s. by KSSLN.

Comment: Isn't it $M_n = X_1 \cdots X_n$? Why do you write that way?

Comment: See my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876399/limit-value-of-a-product-martingale/876406#876406

Answer (score 4):

As Shalop mentioned, you want to assume $X_i$ is not a.s. $1$.

$M_n \to 0$ iff $\ln(M_n) \to -\infty$, so you want to look at
$$S_n = \sum_{i=0}^n \ln(X_i)$$
Note that $\ln(X_i) \le X_i - 1$, with equality iff $X_i = 1$, so 
$\mathbb E[\ln(X_i)] < 0$.  Now use the Strong Law of Large Numbers.

EDIT: It is possible that  $\mathbb E[\ln(X_i)]$ doesn't exist (i.e. 
the integral diverges to $-\infty$.  In that case, replace $\ln(X_i)$ by a truncated version with a finite (and still negative) expectation.

Now SLLN says almost surely 
$$ S_n/(n+1) \to \mathbb E[\ln(X_i)] < 0$$
In particular, for some $\epsilon > 0$ we have almost surely
 $S_n/(n+1) < -\epsilon$ for all sufficiently large $n$.
And then almost surely $S_n < -(n+1) \epsilon \to -\infty$.

Comment: thanks. So the original problem boils down to showing that actually $S_n \to -\infty$. Could you please explain more on the last step using SLLN.